# Soundcloud player stops when changing pages in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, soundcloud

I've been researching this and trying tons of different suggestions to get this to work and thought I would reach out for assistance as I'm still having issues.

I have a multi-external-page jQuery Mobile site. My music.html page loads an iFrame for a SoundCloud player. The player works great, but when I switch to a different page in the site, it stops. I'd love for it to continue playing.

If I am on the music page and I refresh it using the browser refresh, then the player works perfectly. It plays and I can freely move around the site without losing the audio. So this led me to believe that if I could somehow trigger a reload when the music page loads, than the player would work as I'd like it to, but after trying probably a dozen or more reload/refresh scripts, though the results varied, none allowed the player to keep playing.

Right now, I have added data-ajax="false" to the menu link that loads the music page. Even though I lose my "slide" transition for the page, it now works as desired with one caveat; if the music is playing and I click on the Music link from any other page, it reloads the music page and hence stops the music.

Here are some of the things I've tried to no avail:

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", window.location.href, { allowSamePageTransition:true, transition:'none', showLoadMsg:false, reloadPage:true } );
```

Also:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Also:

```
function refreshPage(page){
    // Page refresh
    page.trigger('pagecreate');
    page.listview('refresh');
}
```

Also:

```
function refreshPage()
{
    jQuery.mobile.changePage(window.location.href, {
        allowSamePageTransition: true,
        transition: 'none',
        reloadPage: true
    });
}
```

Also:

```
<div data-role="page" data-cache="false">
```

I don't mind losing the page transitions and keeping the data-ajax="false" when my music page loads. I'm just wondering if there is a way, when the Music button is clicked, to keep the music playing.

Sorry for the long post!! I truly truly appreciate any guidance here.

Thank you so much!!